# Problems with ipv6 address autoconfiguration

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'm trying to get my Linux system to automatically configure an IP address on an interface using stateless auto configuration (slaac). State**ful** autoconfiguration using DHCPv6 works just fine.

1. I start by adding a vlan interface for the appropriate network:

   ```
   ip link add link eth0 name vlan10 type vlan id 10
   ```

   This gets me:

   ```
   $ ip addr show vlan10
   822: vlan10@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
       link/ether 2c:f0:5d:c9:12:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   ```
2. Next, I enable the `accept_ra` sysctl for this interface:

   ```
   # sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.vlan10.accept_ra=2
   net.ipv6.conf.vlan10.accept_ra = 2
   ```
3. I add a link local address to the interface using a randomly generated address:

   ```
   ip addr add fe80::b04f:6d05:d302:266d/64 dev vlan10 scope link
   ```

   So that I have:

   ```
   827: vlan10@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
       link/ether 2c:f0:5d:c9:12:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
       inet6 fe80::b04f:6d05:d302:266d/64 scope link
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   ```

At this point, the interface is up, it has a valid link local address, and I'm able to ping the IPv6 router using its link local address:

```
# ping -c2 fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db%vlan10
PING fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db%vlan10(fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db%vlan10) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db%vlan10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.395 ms
64 bytes from fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db%vlan10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.336 ms

--- fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db%vlan10 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1062ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.336/0.365/0.395/0.029 ms
```

I have the router configured to send router advertisements. I can confirm this is working because the Linux system has already picked up the correct IPv6 default route:

```
# ip -6 route | grep vlan10
2001:470:1234:1234::/110 dev vlan10 proto kernel metric 256 expires 2591803sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vlan10 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db dev vlan10 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1603sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
```

However, the system does not acquire an IPv6 address for the `vlan10` interface.

The corresponding link on the router looks like:

```
# ip addr show switch0.10
14: switch0.10@switch0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:8a:20:bb:05:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2001:470:1234:1234::1/110 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7a8a:20ff:febb:5db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And `/etc/radvd.conf` looks like:

```
interface switch0.10 {
    IgnoreIfMissing on;
    AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
    AdvRetransTimer 0;
    MinRtrAdvInterval 198;
    AdvManagedFlag off;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 600;
    AdvLinkMTU 0;
    AdvReachableTime 0;
    AdvDefaultPreference medium;
    AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvCurHopLimit 64;
    prefix 2001:470:1234:1234::/110 {
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvValidLifetime 2592000;
        AdvPreferredLifetime 604800;
        AdvOnLink on;
    };
};
```

What is preventing my system from automatically configuring an IPv6 address on this interface?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@ek@hachyderm.io](https://hachyderm.io/@ek):

> @larsks 2001:470:1234:1234::/110 needs to be 2001:470:1234:1234::/64.
>
> SLAAC is only specified to work on /64s (RFCs 4862 & 4291).
>
> And yes: changing this has been tried.  There are race-to-the-bottom concerns and other issues that have been debated extensively; /64 is helping leaf networks get a useful minimum amount of space.
>
> Aside: the model for mobile phones is /64 per phone, which allows for IPv6 tethering (via things like 64share).  More like this is in the works.
>
> @larsks Feel free to copy that into stackexchange, if it's of any use.

Looking around, it seems as if [RFC 7421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7421) has a very clear overview of this exact situation.